# protoc generate import path on go source file

Tags: go, proto

I have a pb file in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/cs/p/a/a.proto`, and another pb file in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/cs/p/b/b.proto`. And `a.proto` import `b.proto` like this:

```
import "b/b.proto"
```

Now I enter `$GOPATH/src/github.com/cs/p` and execute the following command:

> protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:. a/a.proto

Then I find `a.pb.go` is generated in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/cs/p/a/`, within which there's such statement: `import "b"`.

When I build the project, it says it cannot find package `b`. What should I do ? Acutally I hope `a.pb.go` import `b` like this: `import github.com/cs/p/b`. Could it be done ?

Answer (score 0):

> Acutally I hope a.pb.go import b like this: import github.com/cs/p/b.
>   Could it be done ?

Yes!

You need to include an import path during the `protoc` compilation step. So assuming your git source lives under the path `$GOPATH/src`, you would add the include flag `"-I.:$GOPATH/src"` like so:

```
protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:. "-I.:$GOPATH/src" a/a.proto
```

---

Once imported, to reference any message types, use the scope path `<package name>.<message name>`.

For example, the (git hosted) definition:

```
// this file resides here: ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/bib/pb/person.proto
package tutorial;

message Person {
  string name = 1;
}
```

would be imported and referenced like so:

```
import "github.com/bib/pb/person.proto"

message AddressBook {
  repeated tutorial.Person people = 1;
}
```